# How can I convert a DF to a String/array and then back to DF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do the following:

I have a DataFrame with two columns (ID,timestamp), both string, that I would like to convert to another format, a String type, or an Array[String] or an Array[Row], I don't really mind but I'd like to convert it back to DF.

I've tried different things:

```
  val aux= df.collect().map { row => row.toString() }
val distDataRDD = sc.parallelize(aux).toDF().show()
```

But I just have one column named "value" that is a concatenation of the two columns from the original DF

I've also tried:

```
  val aux= df.collect().map { row => row.toString() }
val distDataRDD = sc.parallelize(aux).toDF("Id","timestamp").show()
```

but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): value
New column names (2): Id, timestamp
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toDF(Dataset.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder.toDF(DatasetHolder.scala:44)
    at example.tests$.main(tests.scala:60)
    at example.tests.main(tests.scala)
```

Any Idea? thank you

Comment: Why do you want to transform it into an **String**? Maybe you want to store it or send it to other program?

Comment: Yes, right for that reason

Comment: If you want to store it, why not use any of the many methods **Spark** provides to save and read a `DF` to multiple storage systems like HDFS, S3, GCP, Mongo, Neo4j, Cassandra, Hive, HBase, BigQuery, etc. - If you want to send it over the network, then you are using the wrong tool for the job, a `DF` is intended to contain billions of records with a weight of GBs if not TBs, sending that over the network doesn't make any sense. You usually save the `DF` to an intermediate storage and read it back on the other side. And if your `DF` si too small to that be a problem, why are you using **Spark**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by transforming your `Array[String]` to `RDD[Row]` and create DF using `.createDataFrame` with provided schema. Another option is to create DF using `.toDF` then split values and select them as separate cols.

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = Seq(("1","2")).toDF()
  df.show()

  val aux = df.collect().map { row => row.mkString(",") }
  val aux2 = aux.map(s=>RowFactory.create(s.split(","):_*))

  val schema = new (StructType)
    .add("id","string")
    .add("timestamp","string")

  val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(aux2),schema)
  df2.show()

  // another option

  aux.toSeq.toDF("val")
    .select(split('val,",").as("arr"))
    .select('arr.getItem(0).as("id"),'arr.getItem(1).as("timestamp"))
    .show()
```

```
    +---+---+
    | _1| _2|
    +---+---+
    |  1|  2|
    +---+---+

    +---+---------+
    | id|timestamp|
    +---+---------+
    |  1|        2|
    +---+---------+

    +---+---------+
    | id|timestamp|
    +---+---------+
    |  1|        2|
    +---+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but I have one question. If I convert the dataframe to Array, like before, and then I modify the original DataFrame, when I convert the Array back to DataFrame will it be different to the original Dataframe that has been modified?

Comment: Ok, I checked it and the two resultant dataframes are different, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark built-in functions to do that.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "1"),
  ("b", "2")
).toDF()

df
  .select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array($"_1", $"_2"))
  .show()
```

Here, the `array` function put the value in column "_1" and the value in column "_2" in an array for each row.
You can have a look at spark SQL functions to find the one that matches your need. If you don't find one, you'll probably have to make an user-defined function (UDF) but it's not advised as built in functions are more optimized.